# Bootstrap Modal - updating modal id in a php for each loop

Tags: php, api

I am using bootstrap and cards with pop out modals. I want to  update my modal and populate them using my api in a foreach loop. The cards are updating perfectly the issue is the button id for the modal. I am trying to set a new id on each iteration of the loop so that the correct information is displayed within the modal. If I just manually name it the id stays the same on each loop and then the information from the first item in the assoc array is being displayed.

```html
 <?php
                foreach ($goals as $row) {



                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $url_cover = $row['url_cover'];
                    $url_info = $row['url_info'];
                    $id =$row['id'];
                    $num = 5;

                    echo "
    
            <div class='card'>
                <div
                    <div class='card bg-dark text-white'>
                        <img src= $url_cover class='card-img' alt=''...''>
                        <div class='card-img-overlay'>
                            <h5 class='card-title'>$title</h5>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-dark' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#approve{$num}'>
                                +
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div> 

                </div> 
                
                
                <div class='modal fade' id='approve{$num}' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLongTitle' aria-hidden='true'>
                <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                        <div class='modal-header'>
                            <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLongTitle'>$description</h5>
                            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-body'>
                            <p>
                                <a href=$url_info <img src=$url_info title='source: imgur.com'/></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn           btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
                ";

                $num++;
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the pop up code in echo, You can use the below code for it.

```
<?php
foreach ($goals as $row)
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $url_cover = $row['url_cover'];
    $url_info = $row['url_info'];
    $id =$row['id'];
    $num = 5;
    ?>
    <div class='card'>
    <div
        <div class='card bg-dark text-white'>
            <img src="<?php echo $url_cover; ?>" class='card-img' alt=''...''>
            <div class='card-img-overlay'>
                <h5 class='card-title'><?php echo $title; ?></h5>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-dark' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#approve{<?php echo $num; ?>}'>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='modal fade' id='approve{<?php echo $num; ?>}' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLongTitle' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLongTitle'><?php echo $description; ?></h5>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $url_info; ?>" <img src="<?php echo $url_info; ?>" title='source: imgur.com'/></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $num++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying John Doe. Using the above code the cards are populating ok but the button isn't working using php variables. I am thinking though maybe I could use something else rather than PHP for the id that updates on the loop. I am a bit of a novice at this though

Comment: Ok I have actually got this one sorted using my own code above. I can use the php variable but needed to concatenate it with something (non numerical before it) so for example    id = 'goal-$id'  goal is just a random string $id is a unique variable :-)

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you.